# Mobile Emulation >> Element is not clickable - after updating chrome browser and chrome driver to latest version

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chrome Mobile Web Emulation.

**Issue:**

```
After updating chrome and chromedriver, click functionality is stopped working.
```

**Stack-trace:**

```
Not available, no exception or error is thrown.
```

**Chrome version:** `Version 67.0.3396.62 (Official Build).`

**ChromeDriver:** `Version 2.39`

**Selenium:** `Version 3.12.0`

Comment: We are having the same issue. We switched to executing JavaScript to click the element. Hopefully we see a fix soon.

Comment: I had to downgrade my chrome.  Using JavaScript click is not a right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after updating Chromedriver to 2.40.

They provide a version upgrade patch 2.40, just 7 day after releasing 2.39 version.